# How to split a string in Objective-C without breaking the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Xcode throws all sorts of errors when I insert a line break into a string. E.g., this fails:

```
if (newMaximumNumberOfSides > 12) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid maximum number of sides: %i is greater than 
            the maximum of 12 allowed.", newMaximumNumberOfSides);
}
```

But this works:

```
if (newMaximumNumberOfSides > 12) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid maximum number of sides: %i is greater than the maximum of 12 allowed.", 
          newMaximumNumberOfSides);
}
```

I'd prefer the former because it's cleaner to look at (shorter lines), but the code breaks. What's the best way to deal with this? (Subquestion: is this referenced in any of the syntax guides? I searched all my books for "line break" to no effect.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All these should work:

```
NSString *s = @"this" \
        @" is a" \
        @" very long" \
        @" string!";

    NSLog(s);


    NSString *s1 = @"this" 
        @" is a" 
        @" very long" 
        @" string!";

    NSLog(s1);

    NSString *s2 = @"this"
        " is a"
        " very long"
        " string!";

    NSLog(s2);

    NSString *s3 = @"this\
 is a\
 very long\
 string!";

    NSLog(s3);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if (newMaximumNumberOfSides > 12) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid maximum number of sides: %i is greater than " 
            "the maximum of 12 allowed.", newMaximumNumberOfSides);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String literals in C may not contain newlines.  To quote http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html:

> No string literal may extend past the
>   end of a line. Older versions of GCC
>   accepted multi-line string constants.
>   You may use continued lines instead,
>   or string constant concatenation

The other answers already given give examples of both continued lines and string concatenation.